# Is it alright to top off with oil instead of changing after 3000 miles?

Tags: oil

is it ok to top off or change the  oil after 3000 miles?  My husband said that I was 2 quarts. low so he added two quarts. My question is should we have just changed the oil completely or just added the 2 quarts?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Don't add oil without checking the level to see if you need it using the dipstick!

Comment: 2 quarts low,  out of typical 4-5 quart capacity, after just 3000 miles? I'd get that looked at.  Any signs of leakage under the car? Smoke coming out of the tailpipe?  I have a 2016, it uses fully synthetic oil, goes in for an oil change every 10,000 miles. Has an oil level sensor, so there's not even a dipstick to manually check the level.

Comment: @GdD `My husband said that I was 2 quarts. low` so I assume they didn't pull that out of thin air.

Comment: The bigger issue is that you're losing oil. If it's just leaking out of the engine and you need 2 quarts every 1,000-2,000 miles then it's probably okay to just keep adding but that is incredibly wasteful, costly, and not environmentally conscious. If it is not leaking and the oil is actually burning then expect an engine failure in your future because when oil burns, it leaves behind solid crud so topping off the oil is just adding crud. Changing oil in a crud situation helps to remove some of the crud from the engine so it will fail later rather than sooner.

Comment: And don't forgot if the condition worsens (which it will), you're gonna *have* to refill it even sooner.   Forgetting once means you can destroy the engine if it runs out of oil.

Answer (score 27):

You should generally go by the manufacturer's instructions, the car's handbook should specify the change interval - but I don't know of any modern car with that low an interval. Therefore you should top it up unless you're near the interval.

Saying that, if you've lost a significant amount of oil in that time, I'd want to be investigating why...

Answer (score 14):

The 3000 mile oil change interval is a US-specific consumer deception so widely practiced that it has become accepted wisdom. It creates enormous revenue for dealers and garages. Outside the US, most people change their oil far less often.
In fact, manufacturers such as Ford routinely specify oil change intervals of up to 10,000 miles or even more for international markets. During that period it is wise to monitor and top up oil levels but unless there is evidence of discoloration, you should normally find after that period that oil is still 'honey coloured' with only slight darkening from contamination. As the owner of a 2L Ford Mondeo with 172,000 miles on the clock which has had regular services but only oil changes at 10,000 mile intervals. Fingers crossed, it still seems to be in perfect mechanical order. Of course, you would be doing a full vehicle service at those 10,000 mile intervals, not just changing the oil.

Aging vehicles will consume oil at a higher rate. Generally if you're topping up more than a litre every thousand miles or so, that's indicative of a wear issue that will probably result in an emissions problem due to oil burning.

Comment: The new Ford Transit Custom has a 2year/36,000mile service interval

Comment: What the heck engine doesn't turn oil mostly-black after 500 miles? I've yet to own a car that doesn't have that occur. I always perform Used Oil Analysis if I want to actually tell how much life was left in some oil.

Comment: Diesel engine will turn the oil black pretty quick, but in petrol engines it can stay clean looking long past 500 miles if the filter is new and there isn't crud in the bottom of the sump

Comment: The 3000 mile oil change recommendation is a holdover from the days when motor oil had no detergent additives reinforced by most people/manufacturers using significantly undersized filters. It will get you longer engine life, but these days you'll wear out other critical parts that cost too much to replace before the engine goes anyway.

Comment: it will always be cheaper to fix an old car than buy a new one.  You not only have $5000 a year (estimated) in payments, you also have higher insurance and license, etc.  I drive a 2000 customized ford focus zx3 and I've spent 4x more than I paid for the car in repairs (including a tranny swap from a newer model) but the car drives great and I love it and I still am in the black compared to car payments.  As a side note, black oil doesn't mean ruined oil.  The detergent additives are designed to suspend impuritites in it and this discolors is pretty fast.

Answer (score 10):

based on the no information you gave, no manufacturer recommends changing oil every 3000 miles.  Some go as high as 7000 (Toyota) but 4000 is fine for city.  If you are losing oil however, you are either leaking it or burning it.  If you are burning it, then that opening is a two-way street and hydrocarbons from ignition will be polluting the oil.  How bad did it look?  Did it smell burnt?

by no information, I mean you didn't tell us make/model etc.

Comment: Some manufacturers go higher than 7k miles, such as [Jaguar's which have a 15k mile recommended oil change interval](https://www.edmunds.com/car-news/tips-advice/stop-changing-your-oil.html). Definitely agree with your premise, though.

Comment: Anectodal evidence suggests that 30k kilometers or two years (whichever comes first) are not uncommon suggested intervals in European markets. That's roughly 18.5k miles.

Comment: My focus ST has a service interval of 12.5k miles. 7000 seems really low to me.

Comment: I would change the focus at least that often.  there have been reports of engine failures in the newer focuses.

Comment: My Toyota Sienna (2011) has a recommended oil change interval of 10K miles with 0W-20 full synth.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek Not anecdotal evidence! My 10 year old Fiat has manufacturer recommended 30k km or 18k miles service intervals and oil changes - and the 18k mile service is "minor" by the usual standards of non-dealership garages in the UK.

Comment: not that i don't believe you guys, but i would like to see links.  This one says a Toyota van needs 5000 mile service, and i have this van and can confirm that it goes off at 5000 miles.  https://www.yourmechanic.com/article/understanding-toyota-service-indicator-lights-by-brent-minderler

Comment: @JohnLord at https://www.werkstattportal.org/oelwechsel-renault-twingo/ it is specified that the Renault Twingo (just an example I know of) as of model 2001 in many variants needed oil changes every 30.000 km or 2 years, whatever comes first. - They went down to 20.000 km or 1 year in later models, though. Whether for technical or for financial reasons, I do not know. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you had the new oil and filter ready, then I would have changed the lot completely.

But, if you were in the middle of a trip or going somewhere - topping up to the correct level was a good solution as well.

One of those how much time, how much money type situations...

The worst decision - driving it without topping up...

Answer (score 2):

**What type of vehicle? Year, make ,model, miles?**
Most normal vehicles do not need an oil change every 3000 miles. Every car since 1995 should be able to make it to 7000 miles easily on synthetic and 5000 easily on standard oil. Do not trust shops if they say 3000. Also be wary of dealerships having you change earlier than needed. My cars manual says 7500 miles and the dealer kept trying to tell me it must be every 5000. I change my own oil but I wasn't going to lose an argument when they are blatantly lying or just don't know what they are talking about. Check your cars manual or find it online to find the right amount miles before changing your oil.

**If its a truck do you pull or haul a lot?**
Trucks that haul or pull will require more frequent oil changes. Enviroment can dictate that as well. E.G. Dusty air

**Were you driving somewhere at the time of topping it off?**
If you weren't at home or unable to stop at a shop then yes topping it off was the better choice versus going without the proper amount.

**Were you at home when your husband noticed and/or you also have a new filter and new oil ready?**
If you were low on oil AND you had the equipment to change it AND it was time to change it then he should change it as well instead of topping off.

**When was the last time (months or miles) your oil was changed?**
If it's been longer than 6 months and you were that low, then one of two things. Either you are burning and/or losing oil. Or whoever filled it up last time didn't do a good job OR even possibly you are that rough on a vehicle

**Is this the first time that you or your husband has noticed this?**
Has this happened before already and did you actually notice? If you are not sure and you just happened to check the oil then follow this. Place a clean, UNSTAINED piece of cardboard on the clean, dry, ground under your car where the oil pan or oil filter is. The bigger the piece of cardboard the better as oil can come from lots of places. This should allow you to see if you are losing oil through an **EXTERNAL** leak.

If you do not see any oil but you continue to monitor your oil level and it still going down then you are most likely burning it. There is an **INTERNAL** leak and its getting mixed with your fuel. You can tell by the amount of blue,white smoke coming your your tail pipe.

Comment: "service engine soon" alerts for oil changes trigger sooner.  My toyota van has a "maintenance required" alert on the dash that triggers at 5000 miles.

Comment: @JohnLord Those can be changed most of the time

Comment: is that so?  How?  Our shop needs a scanner to just turn the light off on most vehicles.

Answer (score 0):

You should do both (maybe). Topping off oil and changing oil are done for two different reasons and should be handled separately.

All piston based engines burn some amount of oil. The oil is used to lubricate the cylinders and in the process is drawn up into the combustion chamber and a bit of it burns off during the ignition cycle. Newer engines burn far less oil than whats now considered vintage cars. Some older engines its expected to burn in the range of 1 quart every 1000 miles. To ensure that your engine runs properly your car generally requires a specific amount of oil (read off the dipstick). This ensures that the lubrication systems, piping, and sump have enough oil for the system to operate and the scavenge pump to work. Since you are constantly burning oil you need to routinely top it off this is done to ensure proper operation. If your dipstick is low (or below the *low* mark) you should top off immediately even if you plan on changing the oil soon proper oil quantity is important.

Oil changes are a bit different. The general wear on the cylinders causes metal to *very* slowly shave off the sides and end up in the oil system. The fact that most systems are not perfectly sealed also allows particulate matter into the oil system. As this builds up it can clog your oil pump, oil cooler, or other lubrication areas. As such this needs to be routinely flushed and perhaps more importantly you need to replace the [oil filter](https://www.autozone.com/parts/filters-and-pcv/oil-filter-and-oil-filter-accessories) which is typically done during a change. The filter helps to remove particulate matter and can, over time be clogged.

As everyone else has mentioned check the book for the specific car to find out when you should change the oil.

Comment: Oil filters have a bypass valve for when the element gets too dirty.  They will never stop oil flow.  That does allow dirt to fly around freely though...

Answer (score 0):

Oil needs *changing* from time to time because its performance degrades with time, high temperatures and contact with engine metal parts and air.

The question really boils down to whether ***your*** oil is still of acceptable quality after 3000 miles in ***your*** engine. And this depends on:

1. What engine you have
2. What type of oil was put in it
3. Your driving style (gentle, racing, towing etc.)
4. How much time has passed since the last oil change (say if you change oil and drive only 100 miles in 1 year you will most likely need to change it — engine does not preserve oil quality!)

To have an idea of what quality your current oil is, you can:

- Refer to the car user manual and look for recommended oil change intervals (provided that the type of oil you have in the engine is the one recommended in the manual); OR
- Buy an oil analysis kit, take a sample and send it to specialized laboratory. They will tell you for sure how acceptable the oil still is.

So, the answer is:

- If your oil is still good enough, just top it up;
- Otherwise — flush and change (along with oil filter).

Comment: don't forget that it also depends heavily on whether or not you are using synthetic.  It degrades much slower than natural oil.

Answer (score 0):

3,000 miles or even 7,000 miles between oil changes seems absurdly short to me.

My current car has a recommended service interval of 18,000 miles. That's when the oil and filter get changed. After 7 years and 80,000 miles it still runs fine.

Check the oil-change intervals specified in the manufacturer's handbook or service booklet.

---

As others have said, losing two quarts of oil in a short time means you have a leak or are burning oil (e.g. through worn cylinder rings) - that needs investigating and repair.